# Reformat table data sql

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a field `name` with the following rows:

```
`name`
------
John Smith
George Washington
Ash Ketchum
Bill O'Reilly
```

I would like to reformat the rows on output:

```
`name`
------
SMITH, JOHN
WASHINGTON, GEORGE
KETCHUM, ASH
O'REILLY BILL
```

I know I can use `upper(` `x.name` `)` for casing, but how can I reformat the names?

Comment: You can't... What about ROBERTO DA SILVA? Unhyphenated surnames are going to ruin whatever you try. Your only option if you want to be accurate is to create an individual column for each data item. Where the person only had two names, as delimited by a space, you place into these columns. The rest you have to do manually...

Comment: What if I don't have those privileges and can only work with the data at hand. Can't there be some kind of expression utilizing `CASE WHEN` ?

Comment: Yes, you can get close. My point is that the data is stored incorrectly for what you want to do. Therefore you cannot be 100% accurate. Your best option is to fix your data model, which will require some manual work or some highly intelligent parsers. Any answer you get is, by definition, inaccurate; though it may deal with the majority of cases.

Comment: `You can't` seems a little extreme.  Obviously it depends on how he would like to format names with multiple spaces in there, but he could almost certainly find a solution that would do what he needs.

Comment: I like Ben's comment. Reminded me of [Falsehoods Programmers Believe about Names](http://www.kalzumeus.com/2010/06/17/falsehoods-programmers-believe-about-names/) and I had to try to find that article again!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your rdbms is mySql, answer will need to be tailored to differenct dialects of sql.

```
SELECT concat( substring(name, locate(name, ' ')), ', ',  substring(name, 0, locate(name, ' ') - 1)) FROM NAMES;
```

The real problem here however is data integrity. You need to have seperate columns for each peice of the name so that formating in the database is ensured to be consitent. Ideally you would want to be doing this --

```
Select concat(last_name,  ', ', first_name) FROM NAMES;
```

Allowing

```
      'name' 
-------------------
John Smith
Smith, John
J Smith
Smith J
John q Smith
Jhon 'the smithmeister' Smith
```

All in the same column of a table is a bad thing for a number of reasons so this should be explictly prevented.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX( `name` , ' ', -1 ) + ', ' + SUBSTRING_INDEX( `name` , ' ', 1 )
FROM MyTable
```

@Ben, makes a good point about names with multiple spaces in them.  I doubt this would give you the output you want in those cases, but it should get you started.

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
   SELECT Concat(SUBSTRING_INDEX( `name` , ' ', -1 ) , ', ' , SUBSTRING_INDEX( `name` , ' ', 1 )) as name
 FROM your_Table
```